# Localhost only shows blank screen. How can I fix it?

Tags: localhost

I've done this procedure many times before. I created a new pool in IIS, add an application to Default Website and configured its settings.
However this time I cannot connect to the localhost. It doesn't even show any error for starters...Just a blank screen...as simple as that.

I've done anything that had come to my mind(IISReset, stopping and restarting pool and Default Website, restarting the computer, etc.) but it wasn't useful. Please help me, how can I fix it?

Additional info:
Windows 7 SP1
IIS version 7.5.7600.16385
Pool info: ASP.net Version 4.0, Intergrated

Also I'm working with C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to make sure, but have you started the IIS service and it is listening on port 80?

Open your IIS Configuration Panel and make sure that the service is started. Once it is started, going to localhost should display the IIS Welcome Page. You should also check your hosts file as the localhost name may be resolving to other IP Address.

It would really be helpful if you post more details about the problem, like your IIS version and your OS.

EDIT

Reinstall IIS on your computer:

- Go to Control Panel

  - Select Programs and Features
  - Choose add or remove on the upper left
  - Uncheck IIS and all IIS related components
  - Remove the inetpub folder on drive c
  - Reboot
  - Reinstall IIS with the same steps as above by checking all IIS related components

See if it works.

Comment: I've updated the question.
And yes it's started and it's on port 80.

Comment: have you tried pinging 127.0.0.1? If it responds, type it in your browser's address bar.

Comment: Its ping is ok; however it shows me blank screen as well.

Comment: It worked! Now it's showing me an error message:
Handler "ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I fixed it with regiis.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to switch to `master` branch in my project, remove `angular.json` and `package-lock.json` files, then run `npm install` and `npm start` for my front-end project. Then I switched back to my branch and did the same. It's very weird stuff but it helped.

The other thing that helped is changing port for localhost in `package.json`:

```
"start": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --aot --port=8080",
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. you can fix it by this solution:

1.Go to Control Panel

2.Select Programs and Features

3.Select Turn windows features on or off

4.check all IIS services components as below:

[image: IIS Localhost default website shows blank screen windows 7 8 10]

5.then go Internet Information Services (IIS) from start menu

6.from the right panel (Action menu) select Restart

Comment: This is only useful if you want to install IIS and host content on your computer. If using Visual Studio for development, you're likely running IIS Express and none of this is needed, nor would it help.